# Latest state is not reflected after dispatch until next render

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

I have trouble with React state management.
I want to update the global state using Context API after clicking a button, then use the updated state to do something else.

The button dispatches an action to the global state. However, when i try and read the state immediately after, the changes are not reflect until the App re-render.

```
const App = () => {
  const playerRef = useRef();
  const { state, addPlayers } = useContext(playerContext);

  // subscribe playerRef changes to global state,
  useEffect(() => {
    playerRef.current = state;
    console.log("players #", playerRef.current.length);
  }, [state]);

  const add = useCallback(() => {
    // dispatch an add players action to the store
    addPlayers([{ name: "new" }, { name: "newer" }]);

    // PROBLEM: Need latest state value here after dispatch
    // but it's not immediately reflected here
    console.log("player # after dispatch ", playerRef.current.length);

    // do something with the new state
  }, [playerRef, addPlayers]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    add();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Players: {String(state.map(player => player.name))}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        AddPlayers
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here's what the console shows.
[image]

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-morse-r26m1) to the codesandbox to see the full App.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to read the value of `playerRef.current` immediately after a state update:

```
  const add = useCallback(() => {
    addPlayers([{ name: "new" }, { name: "newer" }]);
    console.log("player # after dispatch ", playerRef.current.length);
  }, [playerRef, addPlayers]);
```

However, the value of `playerRef.current` is not updated until the following effect is run:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    playerRef.current = state;
    console.log("players #", playerRef.current.length);
  }, [state]);
```

Which will happen, at the very soonest, after the `useCallback` call is finished*

You should instead read the value of `state`. Refs should be used as instance variables to capture values to be read at a later date; this isn't a really good use-case for them. What you are *trying* to do is essentially this:

```
  const { state, addPlayers } = useContext(playerContext);
  const playerRef = React.useRef();
  playerRef.current = state;
```

Which might as well be:

```
  const { state: currentPlayer, addPlayers } = useContext(playerContext);
```

---

* This probably isn't quite accurate, but either way, you *are* depending on a race condition by doing this.